# Why are there continuous STUN requests and not STUN indications when video call is ongoing in WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, stun

Why do I get repeated STUN requests (STUN message type 0x0001), approx. 100ms apart, from the selected ICE candidate(s), from both peers to the public STUN server after media path is established and media packets communicated.

I thought I would see STUN indications (STUN message type 0x0011) directly between peers to keep the bindings alive.

I had to use wireshark to view this. Initially I was using my own custom STUN server and thought perhaps I was doing something wrong. Then I switched to Google's STUN server and the same behavior was repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indications are an old way of doing this. WebRTC does something called "consent" to check the other side wants to receive the data. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7675 for details